# How to put into a table from a string or an array?

Tags: php, html-table

I can output data to a string or an array like following. And I know the number of columns and rows. For example `$numofrow` is 6 and max `$numofcol` is 5 for this data.

Now what I am not sure is that how I can these to a table. Should I use the array? If so, how? Problem is that some rows have less number of data or td than others.

```
//as an array $mycriteria
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "Criteron A-1,Criteron A-2,Criteron A-3,Criteron A-4,Criteron A-5"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "Criteron B-1,Criteron B-2,Criteron B-3,Criteron B-4,Criteron B-5"
  [2]=>
  string(51) "Criteron C-1,Criteron C-2,Criteron C-3,Criteron C-4"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "Criteron D-1,Criteron D-2,Criteron D-3"
  [4]=>
  string(64) "Criteron E-1,Criteron E-2,Criteron E-3,Criteron E-4,Criteron E-5"
  [5]=>
  string(51) "Criteron F-1,Criteron F-2,Criteron F-3,Criteron F-4"
}

//as a string $mycriteria
mycriteria: string(337) "Criteron A-1,Criteron A-2,Criteron A-3,Criteron A-4,Criteron A-5
Criteron B-1,Criteron B-2,Criteron B-3,Criteron B-4,Criteron B-5
Criteron C-1,Criteron C-2,Criteron C-3,Criteron C-4
Criteron D-1,Criteron D-2,Criteron D-3
Criteron E-1,Criteron E-2,Criteron E-3,Criteron E-4,Criteron E-5
Criteron F-1,Criteron F-2,Criteron F-3,Criteron F-4"
```

Update:

I really need to have empty td as you see below since I am using border lines. Without empty td, it looks ugly.

What I am looking for is the following HTML.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Criteron A-1</td><td>Criteron A-2</td><td>Criteron A-3</td><td>Criteron A-4</td><td>Criteron A-5</td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
<td>Criteron D-1</td><td>Criteron D-2</td><td>Criteron D-3</td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
...

</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to display in html table(tr-td) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want full rows, here's another answer with that:

```
array_walk($my_array,function(&$a) {$a = explode(",",$a);});
echo "<table>";
for( $y=0; $y<$numofrow; $y++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $x=0; $x<$numofcol; $x++) {
        echo "<td>".$my_array[$y][$x]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Required PHP 5.3. If you have lower replace the first line with:

```
array_walk($my_array,create_function('&$a','$a = explode(",",$a);'));
```

Comment: This gives an error telling, Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: You are using the array as shown above, right? Try adding `var_dump($a);` inside that function and see what it gives - it should give strings, but if it doesn't let me know.

Comment: So you mean, your $a is my $mycriteria? Which is my output array?

Comment: No, the `$a` is a temporary variable used by the function. `$my_array` should be your critera in the array format, where each entry is a string.

Comment: Mmmm, var_dump($a); gives Message: Undefined variable: a

Comment: You put that inside the function part, right? Hmm... That's weird, because stuff like this worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want your table in HTML? If so, you'll be looking at something like:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>".str_replace(Array("\n",","),Array("</td></tr></tr><td>","</td><td>"),$mycritera)."</td></tr></table>";
```

Using your string form.

Comment: This gives an error telling, str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given

Comment: Mmm, this does not give empty td, so since I have border, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<table>
<?php
$maxTd = 5;
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
     $subArr = explode(",", $val);
     $count = count($subArr);
?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($subArr as $val1) { ?>
          <td>
              <?php echo $val1; ?>
          </td>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php 
          if($count < $maxTd) {
              for($i = 0; $i <($maxTd - $count); $i++) {
                  echo "<td></td>";
              }
          }
          ?>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: explode is taking 1st string and 2nd key as parameter.

Comment: This won't give empty td though. So giving a border, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need row count or column count for table display.

```
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($my_array as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        $columns=explode(",",$row);
        foreach($columns as $column){
            echo "<td>".$column."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @shin: Now it is working. Small printing mistake was there. I have tested it.